# Symfony: как получить идентификатор связи без дополнительных запросов?

Tags: php, symfony

Модель из документации:

```
class Product
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category", inversedBy="products")
     */
    private $category;

    public function getCategory(): ?Category
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    public function setCategory(?Category $category): self
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Чтобы получить id категории продукта, нужно будет сделать:

```
$product->getCategory()->getId();
```

Это два запроса и гидрирование двух сущностей.

Если будет коллекция, то у нас будет проблема N+1 которую нужно решать дополнительным методом репозитория, а мне всего то, нужно получить идентификатор, который уже лежит в талице продуктов, к которой я делаю запрос.

Как получить идентификатор категории, не работая с сущностью категории?

Comment: Продукты и категории хранятся в разных таблицах, соответственно должна быть свзяь между ними, именно через поле(к примеру) `category_id`. Так тяните из продуктов только поле `category_id`. Или есть какие-то другие нюансы?

Comment: Из ответа с англоязычного SO, сущности как таковой нет, это прокси . (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139970/getting-only-id-from-entity-relations-without-fetching-whole-object-in-doctrine). Удалите ?Category тип возврата и работайте как есть.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Спасибо!